# Portable multithreading support in bytecodes/intermediate languages/compiler backends?

Tags: multithreading, compiler-construction, bytecode, cil, llvm-ir

I've been working on the parser for a programming language that requires multithreading support. While investigating what the backend of my compiler should be, I noticed that I cannot find much information on multithreading for things like CIL, LLVM IR, gcc RTL, or JVM bytecode. I can find some references on how to make such code thread safe, but nothing on how to, say, create or fork threads. I can of course use signals or something to interface directly with the operating system, but that's nonportable and error-prone.

Is it the case that there's simply no portable way for managing threads in these low-level languages? Should I compile to a high(er)-level language like C instead?

Comment: I don't know about CIL, but on the JVM, creating and managing threads is done through the standard library. I imagine it's similar for CIL too. Also, threading in C is a nightmare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JVM byte code you can use any Java libraries, including those that work with threads. The conventional way of creating a thread would be

```
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /// code
        }
    }.start();
```

This code is written in Java. The corresponding JVM byte code can be seen by using javap:

```
   0: new           #2                  // class Main$1
   3: dup           
   4: invokespecial #3                  // Method Main$1."<init>":()V
   7: invokevirtual #4                  // Method Main$1.start:()V
   10: return
```

And Main$1 is a class:

```
final class Main$1 extends java/lang/Thread  {

  // compiled from: Intf.java
  OUTERCLASS Main main ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
  // access flags 0x8
  static INNERCLASS Main$1 null null

  // access flags 0x0
  <init>()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 7 L0
    ALOAD 0
    INVOKESPECIAL java/lang/Thread.<init> ()V
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this LMain$1; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 1
    MAXLOCALS = 1

  // access flags 0x1
  public run()V
   L0
    LINENUMBER 11 L0
    RETURN
   L1
    LOCALVARIABLE this LMain$1; L0 L1 0
    MAXSTACK = 0
    MAXLOCALS = 1
}
```

This code is perfectly portable.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I'm not sure the JVM is a realistic target since this language makes use of [continuation-passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style), but I didn't realize how useful the Java libraries were.